# CSS - Divide the n number of children of a div into rows of 5 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, sass

I have a basic CSS scenario. Given a div, I want to divide its children into `n` rows of 5 columns. The number of children will be dynamic so I am unable to hardcode my code to something like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col col2">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col col3">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col col4">Column 4</div>
    <div class="col col5">Column 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> ....
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can handle this using only CSS and no javascript?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-waterfall-21eg7?file=/src/App.js:0-1048

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempts and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: How exactly are the children going to be dynamic? Javascript? PHP?

Comment: css would be used to style the nth elements, you will not be able to manipulate the dom with CSS

Comment: I will make a demo and share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help you.

Using `display:grid` and a **very simple markup**.

> - Set the `width` of the container and the columns width  will be equally divided by 5.
> - Set the `height` of the rows with `grid-auto-rows` property.
> - No matter how many childs you have. They will fit in the grid. The number of the rows will depend on the number of items.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for! I will try this approach and update the demo above.